# List - breaking out a list of tuples into specific set size, but the size of the sets doesn't have to be the same

Tags: python, python-3.x

I noticed alot of the questions similarly formatted but it seems they specify how many elements in each chunk rather the the number of sets the list is split into.

I have about 3k tuples in a list, everyday it increases by about 10, this is a sample:

```
my_list = [(12,383),(44,23428),(858,12),(1231,59540),(3242,569324),(11,58435),(32, 1231),(13123,34324),(441, 1485),(12111,3923)]
```

I want to break out the list of tuples in 3 groups so there would be 3 , 3, 4 since there are 10  in the my_list example

This doesn't work because it breaks out the list of tuples to have 3 tuples in each group, but I want to make sure there are groups

```
final = [my_list[i * 3:(i + 1) * 3] for i in range((len(my_list) + 3 - 1) // 3 )]
print (final)
```

The output preferable is like below, 3 sets:

```
[(12, 383), (44, 23428), (858, 12)]
[(1231, 59540), (3242, 569324), (11, 58435)]
[(32, 1231), (13123, 34324), (441, 1485), (12111, 3923)]
```

Comment: An exact example of expected output would be clarifying.

Comment: @RunTheGauntlet - In this case it doesn't matter which tuple is in which group as long as they are split into 3 groups (sets?) because the amount of tuples in my list is always increasing.

Comment: Would 4+3+3 also be ok? For 11, is 3+3+5 ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, using a generator in conjunction with `itertools.islice` would be most useful.

```
from itertools import islice

def grouper(lst, ngroups):
    nitems = len(lst)
    grouplen = nitems // ngroups
    it = iter(lst)
    for n in range(ngroups - 1):
        yield list(islice(it, grouplen))
    yield list(it)

for group in grouper(my_list, ngroups=3):
    print(group)

# [(12, 383), (44, 23428), (858, 12)]
# [(1231, 59540), (3242, 569324), (11, 58435)]
# [(32, 1231), (13123, 34324), (441, 1485), (12111, 3923)]
```

There are ways to improve the partitioning. One simple modification would be like this:

```
my_list = [(1, 2)] * 19

def get_grouplen(nitems, ngroups):
    ''' Helper function to determine length of groups '''
    grouplen, excess = divmod(nitems, ngroups)
    if excess > (grouplen / 2):
        grouplen += 1
    return grouplen


def grouper(lst, ngroups):
    nitems = len(lst)
    grouplen = get_grouplen(nitems, ngroups)
    it = iter(lst)
    for n in range(ngroups-1):
        yield list(islice(it, grouplen))
    yield list(it)

# for 3 groups:
for val in grouper(my_list, ngroups=3):
    print(val)

    
# [(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2)]
# [(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2)]
# [(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2)]

# for 4 groups:
for val in grouper(my_list, ngroups=4):
    print(val)

    
# [(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2)]
# [(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2)]
# [(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2)]
# [(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: @KellyBundy does it not? What I understood from the question is that OP wants n groups with equal no. of elements, and if total no. of elements isn't perfectly divisible by n, then excess elements get added to the last group. So I would expect 11 to be divided into 3,3, and 5.

Comment: To me, 3+4+4 seems more desirable. But I asked them about it now.

Comment: @KellyBundy were you referring to something like this, i.e. the edit I just made?

Comment: No, I mean something where the group sizes always differ by at most 1.

Answer (score 1):

Transliterating your requirements into code comes out like this:

```py
NUM_GROUPS = 3
my_list = [(12,383),(44,23428),(858,12),(1231,59540),(3242,569324),(11,58435),(32, 1231),(13123,34324),(441, 1485),(12111,3923)]

len_mylist = len(my_list)

new_size = len_mylist // NUM_GROUPS

short_count = new_size * NUM_GROUPS
excess = len_mylist-short_count

final = [my_list[i*NUM_GROUPS:(i+1)*NUM_GROUPS] for i in range(new_size)]
if excess:
    final[-1].extend(my_list[-excess:])
```